# What is the meaning of the lines written in wsgi.conf

Tags: python, apache, python-3.x, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I'm trying to use Python in my project (without any other framework as requested by my teacher.)

So I've installed Apache 2.x and mod_wsgi and, following a tutorial, I've run my first Python script.

In the specific, the tutorial told me to write in the file `/etc/apache2/conf-available/wsgi.conf` the following line:

```
WSGISriptAlias /test /var/www/html/test.py
```

...and it works!

Despite of this, if I try to change the containing folder of the Python source, it won't work anymore. Can someone tell me how to make this work and what is the meaning of the line written above?

P.S. I need the Python script because my site, in relationship to a form input, have to decide which page to open next.

**So I have something like:**

```
...
<form action="test" method="GET" name="query">
...
</form>
```

I've omitted the .py extension because tutorial said it.

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIScriptAlias.html):

**Description**:    Maps a URL to a filesystem location and designates the target as a WSGI script.

**Syntax**: WSGIScriptAlias URL-path file-path|directory-path

**Context**:    server config, virtual host

So when someone hits the url `/test` on your site, the module at the filesystem path you specify gets run.